How to change server url in swagger ui using org.apache.cxf?
I have app that using cxf dependencies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-openapi-v3</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-common-openapi</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Swagger-ui show wrong server url when I run app in docker:
image
I already ask Apache developers what should I do to fix it.
Then told that I need to use @OpenApiDefinition annotation but nothing has changed after that.
Swagger config class:
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Server jaxRsServer(Bus bus, SampleControllerImpl sampleController) {
        final JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();

        factory.setServiceBean(sampleController);
        factory.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
        factory.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(swaggerFeature()));
        factory.setBus(bus);
        factory.setAddress("/");
        factory.setApplication(new App());
        return factory.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenApiFeature swaggerFeature() {
        OpenApiFeature swagger = new OpenApiFeature();
        swagger.setVersion("1.0.0");
        swagger.setPrettyPrint(true);
        swagger.setContactEmail("example@mail.com");
        swagger.setDescription("Description");
        swagger.setTitle("Title");
        swagger.setSupportSwaggerUi(true);
        swagger.setSwaggerUiConfig(new SwaggerUiConfig().url("openapi.json"));
        return swagger;
    }


@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {
        @Server(url = "http://localhost:8081", description = "Sample Server"),
        @Server(url = "http://somehost", description = "Another Sample Server"),
})
public class App extends jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application {
}

When I run localy nothing has changed too:
image
I also tried changing set OpenApiCustomizer to OpenApiFeature and change url there.
But it didnt helps too.
